# Async web api method to store files on disk but additional save each on to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I noticed that due to the nature of the async upload widget I am using my web api method gets called on multiple threads, one for each file being uploaded. I am trying to combine this with saving all of the files to the database. I am not sure how it is working right now exactly, but at the very end of everything all of the photo records are saved to the database. The problem is I am not able to set the correct sort order for each one of them they all have a SortOrder of 1 except for the last one.

Here is my web api method which is acting very odd:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/photos")]
public IActionResult SavePhotos(int id, IEnumerable<IFormFile> photos)
{
    if (photos != null)
    {
        var product = _unitOfWork.Products.GetProductWithPhotos(id);

        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
            if (photo.Length > 0)
            {
                var productPhotosPath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, _settings.ProductUploadPath, product.Name);

                string randomFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                randomFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(randomFileName, Path.GetExtension(photo.FileName));
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(productPhotosPath, randomFileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

                int maxSortOrder = product.Photos.Any() ? product.Photos.Max(p => p.SortOrder) : 0;
                Photo photoToSave = new Photo()
                {
                    ProductId = product.Id,
                    OriginalImageName = photo.FileName,
                    SavedImageName = randomFileName,
                    SortOrder = maxSortOrder + 1
                };

                _unitOfWork.Photos.Add(photoToSave);
            }
        }

        _unitOfWork.Complete();
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: How should they be sorted? Is it first come first serve? Maybe its better to let the client specify the sort order? If its up to the server you will need some type of synchronization context which might have to run across servers if this should be scale-able to a server  farm. Alternatively you can let the database auto increment the sort order them using an identity column. Or maybe sort order just does not matter and you can order by the assigned image id which should correlate to about when the image is received.

Comment: Did you try to set maxSortOrder before foreach loop and add 1 in the loop?

Comment: @Igor SortOrder is very important. I prefer that the default sort values are the same as the order the user selects the multiple files to be uploaded. But if not then just Amy random order as long as they are sorted like.. 1,2,3,4,5... I already have a reorder function in place that modifies the SortOrders after the fact when the user drags and drops a photo to a different spot. But it is the initial sort order that I am having trouble implementing. The user has no control over it.

Comment: @ademcaglin I don't think this will work because each of the files get processed on a separate thread and none are in the database until the final one is processed. I was trying to get my count based on what was in the database already.

Comment: Do you have control over the client side code? If so that is where you need to specify a sort order and send that with the files to the server. If not then do not set the sort order at all as the server does not know it, order of operations on server != expected sort order, as you have already come to find out. You could also add a 2nd method to order the pictures according to the selection AFTER the upload completes if you find it difficult to specify sort order with upload.

Comment: @Igor I am using the kendo ui upload widget: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/async stock as the async demo shows. I am going to see if I can find a way to send additional info along with the files. If I can't get it to work this way I will just use some kind of update statement on the server after everything is done.

Comment: You will have to initiate that from the client as well as the server side code will not know when everything is done as it is being called multiple times for a single user operation. At that point you could also include the preferred initial sort order (list of key value pairs, key = file name and value = sort order).

Comment: @Igor Yeah, I think the best option is to tap into this: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-upload and create key/value pairs in e.Data which gets sent as an additional param. Make sense?

Comment: Not sure how many pics generally are uploaded but if you are not worried about that+performance you can turn on batching so you get 1 request with everyone instead of XXX requests (1=file). [batch: true](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#configuration-async.batch)

Comment: @Igor I do have that option enabled but it is very strange it doesn't work as it is supposed to because no browsers support it.

Comment: odd. What about looping through the files before upload is called or at the time of `select` event and assigning an extra field sortId that is auto incremented? Then it should materialize on the server in the web api call unless kendo does something behind the scenes and ignores additional properties in which case your earlier idea would be the best option (hook into event and send data after upload completes).

Comment: @Igor thanks for the advice. I got it working after all, something just feels hacky about it though. In the upload event I was able to set e.Data ={sortOrder: sortOrder} as I was looping through the items. So as each thread was opened on the server the sortOrder property was set. I have no idea how and when they all get saved to the database as far as entity framework is concerned but it is all working now.

Answer (score 0):

When you make 5 asyc calls, ain't there a chance that 3 calls hitting together and when these 3 were hit, there weren't any photos in database which makes their sort order as 1 and the rest 2 calls where hit after saving the former 3 calls with sort order 1 which makes their sort order as 2.

How about keeping a created timestamp in database and sort it with timestamp? If you need a sort order property, then have a not mapped property which would be assigned according to the created timestamp.